# В Sublime text Выдаёт ошибку при скачиваний библиотеки

Tags: javascript

[image: Вот ошибка]

что пишет в консоли:

```
Unable to download RailsBase16 Color Schemes. Please view the console for more details.
ignored packages updated to: ["Vintage"]
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
```

P.s. Делал всё, как этот человек с канала Фрілансер по життю, Видео Sublime Text 3 настройка установка плагины // Sublime Text 3 видео обучение // Фрилансер по жизни

*помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен!*

Comment: Может вам лучше стоит перейти на Visual Studio code? Будет по лучше)

Comment: Попытайтесь в ручную перекинуть пакет.

Comment: А как вручную его перенести?
Я просто только-только перешёл на js, css, html с питона